# ANT setting ACL permissions

Tags: symfony, ant, permissions, acl

For my Symfony application I build a deployment script with ANT. In the [installation manual](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup) you can see that you need to set permissions to the `app/cache/` and `app/logs` directories. I therefore use the following approach on command line:

```
sudo chmod +a "_www allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
```

The approach with `setfacl` does not work for me (Mac OS) and the third option with `umask` is no option for me.

So I was thinking about how to do this with ANT and came up with that:

```
<chmod perm="+a '_www allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit'">
    <fileset dir="app/cache" />
    <fileset dir="app/logs" />
</chmod>
```

The problem is it does nothing. I don't even get an error message nor do the permissions change. Any suggestions for that? I can't use a workaround like `perm="0775"` or `perm="0777"` because then I can't delete it anymore with ANT (only with `sudo ant`, but that is not what I want).
Any suggestions how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it:

```
<exec executable="chmod" dir="webroot" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="+a '_www allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit' app/cache app/logs" />
</exec>
```

Answer (score 0):

My system (Debian Wheezy) doesn't seem to support the `+a` attribute, but this has worked for me (second option in the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup)):

```
<exec executable="/bin/sh" dir="${basedir}/app" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="-c"/>
    <arg value="setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX cache logs"/>
</exec>
```

Using `sh -c` seems to be necessary as I couldn't use the backticks for `whoami` without it.

You'll probably need to change `dir="${basedir}/app"` to your own app path.